# How to deserialize generic object from file in Json format

Tags: java, json, generics, gson

How can i tell to method fromJson that I need to return object of type T?
I know that T.class is not possible.

```
@Override
public T getById(String id) {
    File json = new File(folder, id);
    JsonReader reader = null;
    try {
        reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(json.getPath()));
        return gson.fromJson(reader, T.class);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to [compile time type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) your generic parameter `<T>` doesn't exist at run time. As you correctly point out you cannot do `T.class` as there is no `T`.

In order to do what you want you need to request an instance of the `Class` object corresponding to your type parameter be passed into the method:

```
public <T> T getById(final String id, final Class<T> type) {
```

That way you can use the `type` variable to pass into the Gson method

```
return gson.fromJson(reader, type);
```

Comment: Can I do that with TypeToken?

Comment: The whole point is to make a class responsible to know what class of object to return and do this stuff withoug class casting...

Comment: @user1685095 you can't do that with generics because they don't exist at run time.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I did the usual trick (as it turned out to be).

```
public class GenericClass<T> {

 private final Class<T> type;

 public GenericClass(Class<T> type) {
      this.type = type;
 }

 public Class<T> getMyType() {
     return this.type;
 }
```

}